# How to generate model code for "Single DB" using Hibernate Tools through Hibernate Reverse Engineering

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I use the **Hibernate Reverse Engineering** through **JBoss Tools > Hibernate Tools** to generate Model Classes.

There, when I add the Hibernate Configuration and Run it / Rebuild It, it list all the DBs although I mention only one DB in the hibernate.cfg.xml's hibernate.connection.url. 
eg : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booksdb.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booksdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxx</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[image]

Then when I generate the entities code it scans all other Database tables also to generate the entity codes for all. Sometimes it impact by some duplicated tables in different DBs.

**Question :** 
How to do this for single database mentioned in the hibernate.connection.url?

**Hibernate Code Generation Configurations > Main**
[image]

Hibernate Code Generation Configurations > Exporters
[image]

**Hibernate version** : 5.4

**MySQL version Info**

- innodb_version:5.7.26
- protocol_version:10
- version:5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
- version_comment:(Ubuntu)
- version_compile_machine:x86_64
- version_compile_os:Linux

Answer (score 0):

In this screen go to setup near `reveng.xml`. It will ask you to create a xml, from there you'll be able to exclude the databases you don't want.

[image: In this screen]

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table-filter match-name=".*" exclude="true" match-catalog="YOUR_DATABASE_NAME" />
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```